# What did alert the officers to save Hyman Roth?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather-2

In the *Godfather, Part II*, Michael Corleone's henchman Bussetta is sent to kill Hyman Roth but he fails because at the last moment a group of officers enter in the room and kill Bussetta.

Bussetta seems very quiet and benefits from the hospital personnel's lost of attention because of New Years Eve.

What did alert them? Books information are welcome.

[*Who brings a pillow to a gun fight?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVMrFw4r86M)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Books information are welcome.

There is none...there is no source novel for the non-flashback parts of *The Godfather: Part II* so we only have the [**script**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Godfather-Part-II.html) to go on.

This reads

> ```
>   A detachment of military move quickly, accompanied by some
>   of Roth's men, as though they have important news that must
>   be dealt with.
> ```

### News!

Of course there is news, The Cuban revolution has just begun (as evidenced by the news reaching the Presidential Palace where Michael is).

> ```
>   The entire reception has been disrupted for an announcement;
>   all the guests in their formal dress and evening gowns,
>   standing with frightened faces like first class passengers
>   on a doomed ship.  The President himself, his back to our
>   VIEW, is making an announcement in Spanish.  While he
>   speaks, we notice continuous movement of his personal staff,
>   carrying suitcases and possessions.
>
>           PRESIDENT
>     ...Because of serious setbacks of
>     our troops in Guantanamo and
>     Santiago, we feel reluctantly, that
>     we must leave the Capital at once.
>     Myself and my family must bid you
>     goodbye, and good fortune.  We will
>     go directly to Ciudad Trujillo.
> ```

Clearly the military (not police) are on their way to inform the highly influential Hyman Roth and ensure his escape from Cuba...even from his sick bed.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this is based on real events; Roth is based on Meyer Lansky, who had ties to Batista.